# Can multiple chained generators be parallelized on multiple CPU cores

Tags: python, multithreading, generator, python-multiprocessing, coroutine

With standard CPython, it's not possible to truly parallelized program execution on multiple CPU cores using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). This is due to the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

> **CPython implementation detail:** In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.
>
> *Source:* [CPython documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.setDaemon)

Another solution is to use multiple interpreters in parallel with Pythons [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). This solution spawns multiple processes, each with it's own interpreter instance and thus its own independent GIL.

---

In my usecase I have multiple chained generators. Each generator is generating a linked list objects. This list is input to the next generator, which generates again a linked list of objects.

While this algorithm is quite fast, I'm asking myself, if could be parallelized with Pythons multiprocessing, so each generator runs on one CPU core. I think in between of two generators (producer / consumer), some kind of buffer/ FIFO would be needed to decouple the execution speeds.

**My questions:**

- Is such an implementation possible?
- How would a minimal example look like?

---

```
tokenStream = Token.GetGenerator(fileContent)           # producer
blockStream = Block.TranslateTokenToBlocks(tokenStream) # consumer / producer
groupStream = Group.TranslateBlockToGroup(blockStream)  # consumer / producer
CodeDOM =     CodeDOM.FromGroupStream(groupStream)      # consumer
```

Comment: 1) It should be possible; 2.1) spawn the first process that generates tokens, let it output results into a `multiprocessing.Queue`; 2.2) the other process will wait for the first item in its queue and start working as soon as it arrives, then output the result to another queue for the next process; 2.3) finally, some kind of main process will read the results from its queue